# Inserting dynamical number of records into MySQL table with one statement

Tags: mysql

I want to populate a table with N-times a similar record (based on a function) in 1 statement

I'm aware of the concept to insert multiple statements at once based on an other table like:

```
insert into tableX (a, b) select 'foo', someFunction() from tableY limit N
```

But I do not wan't to depend on the record count of tableY during my insert! so I would need something like:

```
select 'foo', someFunction() limit 3
```

Resulting in:

```
foo bar
foo bac
foo baz
```

But I do not seem to find a way to get this working.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no table-valued functions in MySQL (except JSON_TABLE, maybe). If you have MySQL 8+ then use recursive CTE and generate dynamic table with a lot of records, else generate such table in subquery.

Comment: *I do not wan't to depend on the record count of tableY* You may use some system table/view cross-joined to your source table which' records amount is known approximately (for example. `information_schema.parameters` contains ~100 records) and is enough. If you need more copies you may use 2 copies of such table.

Comment: thanks, I'll have a try at that

Comment: It does what I need on native mysql via 
`WITH RECURSIVE cte_count (n) 
AS (
      SELECT 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT n + 1 
      FROM cte_count 
      WHERE n < 3
    )
SELECT n 
FROM cte_count;`
but apparently CTE is not supported on aurora aws. darn, seem to be stuck with looping code-wise. Thanks a lot for your time and help!